# Trying to use exec() to define a variable by setting a string equal to a numpy ndarray, but I get a syntax error. Python 2.7.10

Tags: python, numpy

I have data saved in a text file. I'm trying to save each column of data to a variable defined in a split string list, as follows:

```
list = 'a b c'.split()
data = np.genfromtxt('...3x3data.txt')

for i in range(1,3):
    exec("{} = {}".format(list[i],data[:,i]))
```

If the text file looks like this:
0 1  2
3  4  5
6  7  8

then this should return a = 0,3,6 b = 1,4,7 and c = 2,5,8
but instead I get

> Traceback (most recent call last):   ...
>       exec("{} = {}".format(list[i],matrix[:,i]))     File "string>", line 1
>       b = [ 1.  4.  7.]   ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

except the error arrow points at the decimal after the 4.
The code works if I manually type out the name of each column and define each variable that way but the error comes when using the `exec()` command. I don't know how to google this problem because the error is so vague.

Comment: *"Trying to use exec() to define a variable"* - not even halfway through the title and I'm wondering... why?

Comment: `[ 1. 4. 7.]` is an invalid data-structure for Python,  use `data[:,i].tolist()` or import `np.array` globally as `array` and then you can also do `"{} = {!r}"`. But but [Be careful with exec and eval in Python](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/).

Answer (score 0):

As has been noted often elsewhere, using `exec` to define a variable is a very bad idea. You'd be better off making a `dict` with `'a'` as a key, for example, or any number of other options.

That said, the syntax problem is because while the left-hand side of the execution can be inserted as a string without a problem (e.g. `'a'`), the right-hand side will not be populated with the string `'data[:,i]'` but instead with whatever the string-equivalent is (in this case, based upon the implementation of `__repr__` for `ndarray`), basically `str(data[:,i])` -- which may or may not be a string that can be used as a Python literal in evaluation (in this case, the syntax error tells you that it is not).

So you could change this:

```
for i in range(1,3):
    exec("{} = {}".format(list[i],data[:,i]))
```

into this:

```
for i in range(1,3):
    exec("{} = data[:,{}]".format(list[i], i))
```

This moves the references to the variable being assigned (the right hand side) into the string itself, so that the evaluated statement correctly contains that variable.

A better option could be to use tuple-based assignment, such as:

```
a, b, c = data.T # Transpose since you want separated columns.
```